# Eclipse Debugger throwing Source Not Found Error

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm using Eclipse to debug a Java program I'm developing. Upon stepping into an insert method of one of my classes called from another class I get a source not found error. I have no idea why because when I hit F3 to go to the class' definition it does so without a problem. I'm using Eclipse Kepler

Answer (score 0):

The class in question is found in a jar file on your classpath and jar files do not correspond to editable source.  (but it may have a read-only source zip file attached).

This is most likely because the jar file is placed before the project containing the class on the launchers build path.

Fix your build path.

Comment: How do I fix my build path?

Comment: You might find this video helpful - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-DBitOKVxo.  You want to look for jar files.